How are values assigned to pixels in hyperspectral imaging for airborne cases?
From what I know, hyperspectral images can have up to hundreds of bands. During acquisition, each pixel seems to store only one value. Later, algorithms are used to calculate the missing values across the bands.
Can someone explain:
1. How exactly are the values assigned to each pixel during acquisition?
2. What algorithms are typically used to compute the missing values for all the bands?
3. How do these processes differ in the context of the best airborne hyperspectral imaging satellites?

Any detailed insights or references to resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
